# How to exclude a folder from eclipse android packing?

Tags: android, eclipse, apk

I have a phonegap android projet on eclipse and I would like to know how could I exclude a folder from android apk packing? I have a folder called source which contains css less and other sources and I don't want it to be packed.

Comment: Why can't you move it out of the project folder?

Comment: @yoshi I need to use it inside IDE I can't move.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to right click the folder and click the exclude from build option?

Comment: where is that? I can only find one for resource files. What I wanna exclude is no resource. it is a new source dir.